# How to delete object in jsonb having a certain value

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I have a jsonb type with the following example data:

```
[
  {
    "name": "test1_name",
    "lastname": "test1_lastname"
  },
  {
    "name": "test2_name",
    "lastname": "test2_lastname",
    "order": 14
  }
]
```

Now I'm trying to find a way to delete all documents inside the array where the order field is NOT NULL. I really don't have a clue how to do this. So basically in words I want this:

```
"delete all objects inside the arrays
where order-value is not null"
```

I really don't know how to start with this; since I don't know the array-index of the document I eventually want to delete. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly - and making an additional assumption you have a table that isn't just a single column of a jsonb array but something that looks like this called `my_table`

`| id (primary key) | user_list (jsonb array) |`

Using a with statement - you could do something like the following:

```
WITH user_update AS (
SELECT
    id, users - (index::integer - 1) as new_list
FROM my_table,
    jsonb_array_elements(user_list) WITH ORDINALITY elems(data, index)
WHERE
    elems.data -> 'order' IS NOT NULL
)
UPDATE my_table SET user_list = user_update.new_list from user_update where my_table.id = user_update.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=d32023ee016accdb4033b0745fbb66a6)

```
SELECT
    jsonb_agg(elems.data ORDER BY elems.index)
FROM mytable,
    jsonb_array_elements(mydata) WITH ORDINALITY elems(data, index)
WHERE 
    elems.data -> 'order' IS NULL
```

1. Expand the array into one record per element (use the `WITH ORDINALITY` clause to get the indexes to store the right order)
2. Filter the relevant data
3. Reaggregate the remaining elements using the index.